# webauthn the relying party ID is not a registrable domain suffix of, nor equal to the current

Tags: webauthn

try to do auth process with webauthn resulting with this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The relying party ID is not a registrable domain suffix of, nor equal to the current domain
```

i config current domain as RP but still get this error. is there are way to debug it ?

Answer (score 3):

What is your RP ID and origin?

Requirements from the WebAuthn specification:

> An RP ID is based on a host's domain name. It does not itself include a scheme or port, as an origin does. The RP ID of a public key credential determines its scope. I.e., it determines the set of origins on which the public key credential may be exercised, as follows:
>
> The RP ID must be equal to the origin's effective domain, or a registrable domain suffix of the origin's effective domain.
>
> The origin's scheme must be `https`.
>
> The origin's port is unrestricted.
>
> For example, given a Relying Party whose origin is `https://login.example.com:1337`, then the following RP IDs are valid: `login.example.com` (default) and `example.com`, but not `m.login.example.com` and not `com`.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#rp-id

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to figure this out, I was getting this error because I was encoding the RP ID as a Uint8Array / byte array. Using the RP id directly without any special encoding got rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you are launching your dev server at: http://localhost:3000

Thus the `publicKey.rp.id` should be `localhost`, with its portocal, port and url parameters excluded.